# glGenBuffers fails with 0x0, win7, glew

Tags: opengl, mingw, glew

I try to run a simple renderer on my win7 machine but it dies at the first glGenBuffers call.
The computer has an Intel HD3000 card, with the latest driver (OpenGL 3.0 support).
I use glew 1.10 (self compiled with mingw).
The linker command is:

```
g++ -LC:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib -Lc:\opt\glew-1.10.0\lib -LC:\opt\SDL-1.2.15\lib\x86 -o pysicsdemo.exe src\main.o src\Box.o -lOpenGL32 -lglu32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lglew32.dll
```

And the result is 0x0. Most probably glew can't load the extension, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I forgot to call glewInit. I leave this here just in case if anybody is as stupid as me...

So glew won't find the extensions unless it's properly initialized - explicitly.
Always call `glewInit()` first and check whether it was successful or not by comparing the result to `GLEW_OK`, as written [at the glew website](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).

Comment: For future reference, if `glGen<Anything>` fails, it is usually due to something ***you*** did wrong. Those functions are extraordinarily simple. They do not even create OpenGL objects, they just return and reserve N-many unused names for that type of object. In this case the problem is that `glGenBuffers (...)` was first defined in the VBO extension (~GL 1.5) and Windows only exposes GL 1.1 unless you initialize glew :)